# Same Ajax is not working in IE more than one time

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

i my webpage when the user click forgot password button i ask email , Securitykey etc..  when the user click the sendmail button i send the email,securitykey, etc to a ajax function named 'sendmail(par1,par2,par3)' [Code is below]. The user provide Existing mailid , securitykey... , rtstr[1] is set to 1 [one] . So the 'Mail send successfully' was displayed . But if the user again enter the info [without refreshing the page]and click sendmail button, it didn't work in IE. But it works perfectly in Firefox.

```
var xmlhttp1;
xmlhttp1 = GetXmlHttpObject();
function sendmail(Mailforpwd, Secquestion, Secanswer) {
  if (xmlhttp1 == null) {
    alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return;
  }
  var url = "SendEmail.php";
  url = url + "?Email=" + Mailforpwd;
  url = url + "&Squestion=" + Secquestion;
  url = url + "&Sanswer=" + Secanswer;
  xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
  xmlhttp1.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp1.send(null);
  function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 4) {
      var Result = xmlhttp1.responseText;
      rtstr = Result.split('#');
      //alert(xmlhttp1.responseText);
      //alert(rtstr[0]);
      //alert(rtstr[0]);
      if (rtstr[0] == 1) {
        document.getElementById("Errorcredentials").innerHTML = "Mail send successfully";
      }
      else if (rtstr[1] == 0) {
        //alert(document.getElementById("Errorcredentials").innerHTML);
        document.getElementById("Errorcredentials").innerHTML = "Please provide Exist information";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("Errorcredentials").innerHTML = "There is a problem in sending mail, please try after sometime";
      }
    }
  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return null;
}
```

Here my problem is at second time the function stateChanged() was not called , if i put a alert in this function , first time it display alert box , But next time it won't. This is my problem . The sendMail.php was called eachtime .

Comment: Similar to what @Jason told. `url = url + '?rnd=' + Math.random();`

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I have this problem it is because IE caches your AJAX request. The best way to avoid this is to append a random number as a key in your query string each time.

```
url = url + "&rand=" + Math.random();
```

Comment: @Lijo no problem. although, you shouldn't really be supporting IE8 anymore :)

Comment: I had to make it as `url = url + '?rnd=' + Math.random();`

Comment: well, yes, if you don't already have a query string you need to make sure you have one.

Answer (score 3):

Or, better, since your AJAX request appears to be causing some action to happen server-side, why don't you use HTTP POST instead of GET?

xmlhttp1.open("POST", url, true);

Answer (score 1):

This is a caching problem. Append current date time to your url to make it unique.

```
url = url + "&rand=" + (new Date());
```

Answer (score -2):

just swap these lines in your code.

```
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = stateChanged; 
xmlhttp1.open("GET", url, true);
```

after fixing it looks like

```
xmlhttp1.open("GET", url, true); 
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
```

thats it!!
skypeid: satnam.khanna

Comment: Signatures are very bad form here. Please refer to the FAQ for more details.